# Resharper autocompletes the wrong method

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, resharper

Resharper correctly suggests and preselects the generic version of method I want to complete. However after hitting 'Enter' it autocompletes another method.

[image: Correctly preselected method]

Wrong method is completed

[image]

How is this possible and how can I fix this ?

Resharper 10.0.2

Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1

Unity 5.3.1f1

Comment: Could you add your version of R#, visual studio and also the framework version you use.

Comment: See Alexander's answer (he works for R#) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you experience the same R# bug as described in [the following YouTrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-451813). Such issue has been fixed in R# 10.1 branch and will be available in ReSharper 10.1 release.

Comment: Thanks, what is the ETA on the release ?

Comment: We are expecting to release R# 10.1 in April.

Comment: Alexander, Is the issue of resharper running unit test for nunit3 in an aspnet5 project going to be fixed in 10.1 release?

Answer (score 2):

Either it's a bug or a feature not present in your version, but **in R# 9.2, the behaviour is what you expect.**

So if you're in R# 10, you can try to downgrade with your current license (or upgrade if you're in R# with a lower version, IMHO the upgrade to higher version is free if I remember well).

By the way, if MuhKuh is right on R#10, then you're only choice is to type "`<YourType>`" unless there is an hidden configuration field to go back to legacy behavior.

**Check [here](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207242355-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-) for all possible versions.**

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem recently but in monodevelop so I don't think it's a bug - the only way I managed to resolve the problem is to carefully look at your code and rename anything that uses the same name as your method (which the code has access to).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a wrong auto completion.
What you are seeing here are 2 different features of ReSharper.

The first one is the auto completion which shows you the available overloads.
The second one (after you accept with Enter) is the best candidate for the parameters you are typing.

I am not sure what algorithm they use, but you can simulate that behavior by creating 2 methods like this.

```
public void Test(int val)
{
}

public void Test(string val)
{
}
```

You will notice that depending on if you type a number or start typing " for a string, the popup will switch to the correct overload.

Comment: With the version 9.2, the problem is not present: what you select is what you get especially when there is generic

Comment: ReSharper 10 groups the generic and non-generic ones in the same item and there is no possibility to select anything, as there is only one item in the list. You can however accept the auto-completion with "<" instead of Enter to select the generic version.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a correct intellisense.

This will divide the two conditions.

1. map.AddComponent() : hint AddComponent(Type) and AddComponent(string)
2. map.AddComponent() : hint AddComponent()

you should input map.AddComponent to complete it